# How can I transfer usdt if I do not have eth on account?

Tags: erc-20

Is there any way I can transfer the usdt if I do not have any eth on my account?
Actually I want to develop a payment gateway and give each customer an address to pay usdt, Once the payment done, the usdt will be transferred to my main eth account.

Comment: I want to transfer my usdt to my btc but I dont have ethurum

Comment: You need to buy ETH.

Answer (score 0):

You need ether to pay for the gas cost of the transaction and smart contracts can currently not pay for gas cost. Your best bet is to use a relay service:
Sign the transaction, send it to someone with ether, pay them in USDT and let them execute the transaction on the blockchain.

You can build a relay yourself or use one of the many services, like this decentralized one: https://gsn.openzeppelin.com/

Comment: Thanks 
Do you mean one account can just sign the token transfer transaction but another different account can run send raw transaction although the transaction is between A and B but C can use sendrawtranction to put this transaction on to blockchain

Comment: Thanks where can I find the relay service and which one is easy to integrate?

Answer (score 0):

There are some tokens that allow us to pay by generating signature off-chain and execute it on-chain such as DAI.

Please refer [this blog](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-code-gas-less-tokens-on-ethereum-43u3ew4) how we can do this with DAI stablecoin.
But I don't think we can do the same with USDT as USDT does not support such `permit` function in its smart contract.